# Skipping Specific Component Styles

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I try to do something realy basic what is described in spartacus documentation https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/#skipping-specific-component-styles

At file *src/styles.scss*:

```
$styleVersion: 4.3;
$skipComponentStyles: (cx-mini-cart, cx-product-carousel, cx-searchbox);
@import '~@spartacus/styles/index';
```

But looks like **$skipComponentStyles** variable not works as expected, no changes at UI. Is this a bug of lattest release or do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was not working for me too before I changed the styles imports from angular.json to styles.scss.

**Before**:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/user.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/storefinder.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/product.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/order.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/checkout.scss",
              "src/styles/spartacus/cart.scss"
            ],
```

**After**:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

styles.scss

```
$skipComponentStyles: (cx-mini-cart);
@import '~@spartacus/styles/index';

@import "styles/spartacus/user";
@import "styles/spartacus/storefinder";
@import "styles/spartacus/product";
@import "styles/spartacus/order";
@import "styles/spartacus/checkout";
@import "styles/spartacus/cart";

@import 'styles/custom-styles';
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps. It fix two issues: First you can not use '$skipComponentStyles' as described in documentation. Second that you have a predictable order of your final css.